# How to clear EHCache?

Tags: ehcache, activejdbc, javalite

I'm in the process of upgrading JavaLite ActiveJDBC from EHCache 2.x to v 3.x. 
It looks APIs changed dramatically, and I can find equivalents of what I need in v 3.x, except for one: How  to clear all caches? For example, in v2.x, I could do this:

```
net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();
//... code
cacheManager.removalAll();
```

How can I do this in EHCache 3?

Answer (score 2):

Clarification: `CacheManager.removalAll()` is a method that not only clear caches, but removes them completely. It is deprecated in the latest version and replaced with `CacheManager.removeAllCaches()` to better indicate its purpose.
Caches will no longer be alive and cannot be used anymore if you were to keep a reference to one of them.

The equivalent in Ehcache 3 would be to invoke: `CacheManager.close()` which would close all caches and then release all resources held by the `CacheManager`.

Hard to conclude with the disconnect between what I understand the stated goal to be (clear data from caches) and the Ehcache 2 method used (remove all caches) if Ehcache 3 satisfies it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, in version 3, I would: `cacheManager.close();` to release all caches. Should I then loose reference to this object? Also, if I need to recreate it, I would then create a new instance of CacheManager, correct?

Comment: No, in 3 the lifecycle is explicit and properly handled. You can simply invoke CacheManager.init() to re-enable it, it will also re-initialise all caches configured in it.

Comment: So, the method `CacheManager.init()` will clear existing caches too?

Comment: Absolutely not, `CacheManager.init()` will properly initialize a cache manager, either at time of creation or after it has been `CacheManager.close()`.